# React file upload how to show toast on upload success or failure

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, materialize

I have a file upload component as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class FileUploadForm extends React.Component{
  render (){
    return (
      <div class="row">

               <div class="file-field input-field">
                  <div class="btn">
                     <span>Browse</span>
                     <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} ref = "file"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                     <input class="file-path validate" type="text"  placeholder="Upload multiple files" />
                  </div>
               </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChange(e){
    console.log("FileUploadForm: upload files selected")
    let files = e.target.files;
    if(files.length == 0){
      return
    }
    console.log(files[0]);
    this.props.onFileUploadRequested(files);
  }
}
```

and here is the container to connect it to redux:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { uploadFiles } from '../actions.js';
import FileUploadForm from '../components/FileUploadForm';

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onFileUploadRequested: (files) => {
      dispatch(uploadFiles(files));
    }
  }
}

const FileUploadContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FileUploadForm);

export default FileUploadContainer;
```

I am using materialize CSS which has a Toast component.

```
// Materialize.toast(message, displayLength, className, completeCallback);
  Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000) // 4000 is the duration of the toast
```

I hit an API to upload images which tells if the call failed or succeeded. Then I dispatch actions which change state field (fileUploadStatus)as:

- FILE_UPLOAD_SUCCEEDED: fileUploadStatus = SUCCESS
- FILE_UPLOAD_FAILED: fileUploadStatus = FAILURE

the initial value of this field is READY.

I am not sure how to show toast on upload success or failure.

Following are my queries:

- Is it advisable to use a global message component and show all such messages of API call success or failure in that or something inside file upload component only?
- Considering the use of field 'uploadStatus' in stated in above, how do I revert it to READY state so that the message is not shown on further render?

I am a complete beginner to developing single page applications and have only working knowledge of javascript. I am stuck on this on for quite some time now. Please suggest if you feel there are some gaps in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

1) There are a number of ways to solve this. What has worked for me is to expose a `toast` function via [`context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), that lives in the top-most component. In React, `context` should be used sparingly but this scenario is acceptable IMO. For example:

```
class App extends Component {
  toast() {
    ...
  }
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      toast: this.toast
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Child />
    );
  }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
  toast: PropTypes.func
};

class Child extends Component {
  ...
  onSomeEvent() {
    this.context.toast('Something happened.');
  }
}

Child.contextTypes = {
  toast: PropTypes.func
};
```

2) `Materialize.toast()` has an optional callback function as a 4th argument which you can use however you want. In this case, it can be used to revert your `fileUploadStatus`.